# Asignar Formato numérico a cadena en Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, .net

Necesito darle formato de numero con 2 decimales a una cadena pero no quiero que me muestre los separadores de miles (porque me da problemas esto para guardar en Mysql) sino solo los 2 decimales ejemplo

```
Dim Monto as String = "000001804032"
```

y me deberia devolver 18040.32

yo estoy haciendo asi pero no me funciona.

```
Dim TmpMonto As Double
TmpMonto = cdbl(Monto)
```

Comment: Creo que en vez de resolver el problema (guardar en MySql) estás creando un nuevo problema. Si tienes valores `double` debes recogerlos como tal y manejarlos del mismo modo. ¿Por qué Monto es string?

Comment: Trate de simplificar por q en en realidad recibo una larga String de donde se extraen diversos datos entre ellos el que puse Dim Monto as String = "000001804032".  Lo de Mysql no es problema solo lo que consulto ...

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un `string` deberás modificarlo y poner el punto decimal manualmente antes de convertirlo a `double`. Tomamos como valor decimal los dos últimos dígitos:

```
Dim Monto as String = "000001804032"
Monto = left(Monto, len(Monto)-2) & "." & right(Monto, 2)
Dim TmpMonto As Double
TmpMonto = cdbl(Monto)
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias!! con eso ya me arreglo!!!